# Change values in list of dictioneries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have huge lists of dictionaries and i must to change date format in key `<DATE>` in each dictionary on list.

I write code like that but it doesn't work:

```
dict_list = [
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980317', '<CLOSE>': '11.633', '<VOL>': '67931'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980318', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '115169'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980319', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '75305'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980320', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '53504'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980323', '<CLOSE>': '10.379', '<VOL>': '27581'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980324', '<CLOSE>': '10.228', '<VOL>': '37328'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980325', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '28739'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980326', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '45352'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980327', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '42585'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980330', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '21260'}
]
    
for dictionary in dict_list:
    for date in dictionary:
        date = dictionary["<DATE>"]
        year = date[:4]
        month = date[4:6]
        day = date[6:]
        date = f"{year}-{month}-{day}"

print(dict_list)
```

I try to add:

`dictionary.update({"<DATE>": date})`

but output doesn't look good. Should be:

`{...'<DATE>': '1998-03-17'...}`

was:

`{...'<DATE>': '1998------0-3-17'...}`

I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the whole script? `f"{date[:4]}-{date[4:6]}-{date[6:]}"` does work...

And in any case you should probably parse the date string into a `datetime` object and output it from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to loop over `dictionary` again?

This line:

```
    for date in dictionary:
```

That lane iterates over the **keys** of the dictionary. As a result, the logic within repeatedly takes the first four digits of the `<DATE>` field and slice'n'dice it, like so:

```
19980330        ==> 1998|03|30
1998-03-30      ==> 1998|-0|3-30
1998--0-3-30    ==> 1998|--|0-3-30
1998----0-3-30
```

1. Remove the second loop
2. Also, what's the point of calling `.update()` there? Just assign directly, like so:
   `dictionary["<DATE>"] = date`

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your second loop, which makes your dictionary updated 4 times. Here is my solution:

```
dict_list = [{'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980317', '<CLOSE>': '11.633', '<VOL>': '67931'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980318', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '115169'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980319', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '75305'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980320', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '53504'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980323', '<CLOSE>': '10.379', '<VOL>': '27581'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980324', '<CLOSE>': '10.228', '<VOL>': '37328'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980325', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '28739'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980326', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '45352'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980327', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '42585'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980330', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '21260'}]
     
for dictionary in dict_list:
    date = dictionary["<DATE>"]
    year = date[:4]
    month = date[4:6]
    day = date[6:]
    date = f"{year}-{month}-{day}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, you have to put a condition to check the `<DATE>` key. Only this addition will give you the expected output.

**Your input list**

```
dict_list = [{'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980317', '<CLOSE>': '11.633', '<VOL>': '67931'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980318', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '115169'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980319', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '75305'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980320', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '53504'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980323', '<CLOSE>': '10.379', '<VOL>': '27581'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980324', '<CLOSE>': '10.228', '<VOL>': '37328'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980325', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '28739'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980326', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '45352'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980327', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '42585'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980330', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '21260'}]
```

Modified code.

```
for dictionary in dict_list:
    for key in dictionary:
        if key == "<DATE>" :
            date = dictionary[key]
            year = date[:4]
            month = date[4:6]
            day = date[6:]
            date = f"{year}-{month}-{day}"
            dictionary[key] = date
        else:
            pass

print(dict_list)
```

**Your Expected Output**

```
[{'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-17', '<CLOSE>': '11.633', '<VOL>': '67931'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-18', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '115169'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-19', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '75305'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-20', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '53504'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-23', '<CLOSE>': '10.379', '<VOL>': '27581'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-24', '<CLOSE>': '10.228', '<VOL>': '37328'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-25', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '28739'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-26', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '45352'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-27', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '42585'}, {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '1998-03-30', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '21260'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was with your inner loop which is unnecessary:

```
dict_list = [
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980317', '<CLOSE>': '11.633', '<VOL>': '67931'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980318', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '115169'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980319', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '75305'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980320', '<CLOSE>': '10.481', '<VOL>': '53504'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980323', '<CLOSE>': '10.379', '<VOL>': '27581'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980324', '<CLOSE>': '10.228', '<VOL>': '37328'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980325', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '28739'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980326', '<CLOSE>': '10.131', '<VOL>': '45352'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980327', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '42585'},
    {'<TICKER>': 'HDR', '<DATE>': '19980330', '<CLOSE>': '10.027', '<VOL>': '21260'}
]

for dictionary in dict_list:
    date = dictionary["<DATE>"]
    year = date[:4]
    month = date[4:6]
    day = date[6:]
    date = year + '-' + month + '-' + day
    dictionary["<DATE>"] = date

print(dict_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for dictionary in dict_list:
    date = dictionary["<DATE>"]
    year = date[:4]
    month = date[4:6]
    day = date[6:]
    date = f"{year}-{month}-{day}"
    dictionary["<DATE>"] = date
```

You should set value in the dictionary, as "date" is a value type, so when iterating, it is copied in the "date" variable, so changes are not applied to value in the map(it would if it was a reference type)

Comment: "value type" and "reference type" are not concepts in Python. For all types, variables are not references, but bindings. Changing a binding does not change the value previously bound.